# d3 detect drag element onto a line

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I have been looking for a solution to a problem that I have. I would like to be able to drag a svg rect element created in d3 onto a line created in d3. I would like to detect when the rectangle has overlapped the line and break the line into three creating nodes that attach to the side of the rect. I want to this happen automatically. So, I have to be able to detect when I am dragging the rect onto the line and identify where I should break the line into two.

Thanks.

Comment: The [intersection library](http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/) can help you with that.

Comment: Are you aware of any particular examples?

Comment: No, I'm not aware of anything that does what you want.